# FParsec: how to parse date in fparsec (newbie)

Tags: f#, parsec, fparsec

I am using the [Bill Casarin](http://blog.jb55.com/post/4247991875/f-csv-parsing-with-fparsec) post on how to parse delimited files with fparsec, I am dumbing the logic down to get an understanding of how the code works.  I am parsing a multi row delimited document into Cell list list structure (for now) where a Cell is a string or a float. I am a complete newbie on this.

I am having issues parsing the floats - in a typical case (a cell delimitted by tabs, containing a numeric) it works.  However when a cell happens to be a string that starts with a number - it falls apart.

How do I modify pFloatCell to either parse (although the way through the tab) as a float or nothing?

Thank you

```
type Cell = 
    | String of string 
    | Float of float
.
.
.
let pStringCell delim = 
    manyChars (nonQuotedCellChar delim)
    |>> String

// this is my issue. pfloat parses the string one 
// char at a time, and once it starts off with a number 
// it is down that path, and errors out
let pFloatCell delim = 
    FParsec.CharParsers.pfloat
    |>> Float

let pCell delim = 
    (pFloatCell delim) <|> (pStringCell delim)
.
.
.
let ParseTab s  =
  let delim = "\t"
  let res = run (csv delim) s in
    match res with
     | Success (rows, _, _) -> { IsSuccess = true; ErrorMsg = "Ok"; Result = stripEmpty rows }
     | Failure (s, _, _) -> { IsSuccess = false; ErrorMsg = s; Result = [[]] }
.
.
.
let test() =

    let parsed = ParseTab data
```

oops late for me last night.  I meant to post the data. This first one works

```
let data = 
    "s10 Mar 2011 18:28:11 GMT\n"
```

while this returns an error:

```
let data = 
    "10 Mar 2011 18:28:11 GMT\n"
```

returns, both with and witout ChaosP's recommendation:

> ErrorMsg = "Error in Ln: 1 Col:
>   3\r\n10 Mar 2011 18:28:11 GMT\r\n 
>   ^\r\nExpecting: end of file, newline
>   or '\t'\r\n"

It looks as though the attempt is working fine. in the second case it is only grabbing up to the 10 - and the code for **pfloat looks only up to the first whitespace**.  I need to convice pfloat that it needs to look all the way up to the next tab or newline regardless of whether there is a space before it; write my own version of pfloat by performing a Double.Parse - but I would rather rely on the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems the text you'll be parsing is a bit ambiguous you'll need to modify your `pCell` parser.

```
let sep delim =
     skipString delim <|> skipAnyOf "\r\n" <|> eof

let pCell delim = 
    attempt (pFloatCell delim .>> sep delim) <|> (pStringCell delim .>> sep delim)
```

This also means you'll need to modify whichever parser uses `pCell`.

```
let pCells delim =
    many pCell delim
```

**Note**

The `.>>` operator is actually quite simple. Think of it like the leap-frog operator. The value of the left hand side is returned after applying the right hand side and ignoring the result.

```
Parser<'a, 'b> -> Parser<'c, 'b> -> Parser<'a, 'b>
```

Comment: thx, it did not working for me though: ErrorMsg = "Error in Ln: 1 Col: 3\r\n10 Mar 2011 18:28:11 GMT\r\n  ^\r\nExpecting: end of file, newline or '\\t'\r\n"

Comment: updated tge example above to include my previous comments, in orderto easier to read.